# Does this sequence converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Does the sequence $x_n=3^n−2^n$ converge? I can show that it is increasing but how to show that it is bounded?

Comment: It might be hard to show it is bounded.

Comment: @GitGud do you know any other way to solve my problem?

Comment: @GitGud because it is unbounded :)

Comment: @math137 how to prove that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**

For $n \geq 2$ we have $(\frac{3}{2})^n-1 >1$. Thus
$$3^n−2^n=2^n [(\frac{3}{2})^n-1]>2^n$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Note that $3^n-2^n=3^n\cdot(1-(\frac{2}{3})^n)$.

Answer (score 1):

You can show: $3^n - 2^n > n^2$ by induction on $n > 3$, and this means the sequence is unbounded, and diverges to $\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$3^n - 2^n = (2+1)^n-2^n=n 2^{n-1}+\cdots\ge n$